# Cannot implicitly convert type `Steamworks.CSteamID' to `float'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamworks-api

I'm currently using Steamworks.net with Unity3d and C#. What I want to do is to get Steam users ID, in this case my own and then execute a function.

This is what I have so far:

```
private static float berdyevID = 76561198040013516;
private static float steamID;


void Start() {

    if(SteamManager.Initialized) {

        string name = SteamFriends.GetPersonaName();

        // get steam user id
        steamID = Steamworks.SteamUser.GetSteamID();

        // see if it matches
        if (berdyevID == steamID) {

            Debug.Log ("Steam ID did match");
        } else {

            Debug.Log ("Steam ID did not match");
        }


    }

}
```

I am getting an error from Unity which states:

Cannot implicitly convert type `Steamworks.CSteamID' to`float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Which confuses me. I tried doing my research on google to find a possible fix, but couldn't find anything. Can anyone help?

**EDIT**:

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
private static ulong berdyevID = 76561198040013516;
private static ulong steamID;

void Start() {

    if(SteamManager.Initialized) {

        string name = SteamFriends.GetPersonaName();

        // get steam user id
        steamID = Steamworks.SteamUser.GetSteamID();

        // see if it matches
        if (berdyevID == steamID) {

            Debug.Log ("Steam ID did match");
        } else {

            Debug.Log ("Steam ID did not match");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `GetSteamID()` return an object of type `Steamworks.CSteamID` which is not assignable to the variable `steamID` of type `float`.

There is a `ulong` variable named `m_SteamID` variable in the `CSteamID` struct. That's where the id is located.

```
private static ulong berdyevID = 76561198040013516;
private static ulong steamID;


void Start() {

    if(SteamManager.Initialized) {

        string name = SteamFriends.GetPersonaName();

        // get steam user id
        steamID = Steamworks.SteamUser.GetSteamID().m_SteamID;

        // see if it matches
        if (berdyevID == steamID) {

            Debug.Log ("Steam ID did match");
        } else {

            Debug.Log ("Steam ID did not match");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay.. What would I do then?

Comment: Look at the api and see how it returns the id from that class

Comment: @Programmer its funny because I already tried ulong and it didn't work. Same error but ulong instead of float, obviously

Comment: @Programmer what do you mean if it works now? Your code looks the same as a minute ago? ulong didn't work.

Comment: Add **Edit** to your new question and add your new code. to it

Comment: What? What new question? Ulong and float both didn't work. I'm confused? @Programmer

Comment: Stop. I modified this answer with a code and you claimed that it doesn't work. Just modify your question and add that new code that doesn't work.

Comment: @Programmer, i've done that, even though I did not see a point.

Comment: You tried ulong. But did you try to get the `m_SteamID` part of the `GetSteamID()` function?

Comment: Seriously? *"No point to that"* but you missed the most important part of the which was `m_SteamID`.... If you are having a hard time reading then just copy the code in the answer. It is `steamID = Steamworks.SteamUser.GetSteamID().m_SteamID;` **not** `steamID = Steamworks.SteamUser.GetSteamID()` and I asked you to add "EDIT" for your edit. Had to roll back your question EDIT to fix the edit part. Read the answer again.

Comment: That's what I get for doing multiple things at a time. My apology. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Programmer Thanks